# what is the difference between serverpod and dart frog

Tags: flutter, dart, backend

what is the difference between Serverpod and Dart Frog? Do they both for backend purposes for Flutter apps or do they have more differences than similarities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Serverpod:**

- Primarily an app and web server written in Dart. It aims to provide a
  full-stack solution for Flutter developers, including generating both
  the backend server and a basic Flutter frontend for seamless
  integration.

**Dart Frog:**

- A minimalist backend framework built on top of the Shelf framework.
  It focuses on providing the essential tools for building backend
  services and APIs quickly and efficiently in Dart.

Answer (score 1):

[Dart Frog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlFYxNXERyI&list=PLKKf8l1ne4_h9ttT_ihJ7xelHU1-o3w90) is a backend framework. [Serverpod](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yn9pQp4Wc7E&list=PLKKf8l1ne4_hHNjCzifoPma3ZAk8hZuia) is an app and web server.